# Android system app as device administrator without user activation

Tags: android, system

I want to build an Android service that uses the Device Administration API (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).

The problem is that I don't want the user to enable my service. I know that this is not possible for a regular application by I am cooperating with an OEM so I am going to use a custom ROM and my application can be a pre-installed system app.

So my final question is if a system app with the right permissions is able to use  Device Administration API without needing user activation of the app as device administrator. If this is possible can someone tell me how this is done? Please help me.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have exactly the same issue with an oem.